# Как программно изменить ТЕКСТ Пункта Меню Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Всем самого наилучшего! Помогите, пожалуйста, в одном вопросе. Мне нужно, чтобы после очередного
нажатия на Пункт Меню, текст этого Пункта Меню - ИЗМЕНЯЛСЯ. Все прекрасно видно из маленького
примера:

```
    from tkinter import *


class MainWindow:  # Класс - Главного-Окна
    # (Основное Окно Игры)
    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("+550+300")  # ("250x150+300+300")
    window.resizable(False, False)  # Изменение размера окна

    # (Для Пункта Меню - Открыть/Закрыть)
    MENU_POINT_TEXT = 'Открыть'
    MENU_POINT_FLAG = False

    def start(self):  # вывод - Главного-Окна Игры
        self.init_ui()  # создание - Главного-Окна Игры
        # (Главный-Цикл Игры)
        MainWindow.window.mainloop()

    def init_ui(self):  # создание - Главного-Окна Игры
        # (Меню)
        menubar = Menu(self.window)
        self.window.config(menu=menubar)
        # (Пункты Меню)
        settings_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        settings_menu.add_command(label=MainWindow.MENU_POINT_TEXT, font='Arial 8 bold', command=self.open_close)
        # (Выход)
        settings_menu.add_separator()
        settings_menu.add_command(label='Выход', font='Arial 8 bold', command=self.window.destroy)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Файл', menu=settings_menu)

    @classmethod
    def open_close(cls):
        if not cls.MENU_POINT_FLAG:
            # (Открытие)
            cls.MENU_POINT_FLAG = True
            cls.MENU_POINT_TEXT = 'Закрыть'  # (НЕ РАБОТАЕТ !!!)
            print('***  ОТКРЫЛИ !  ***')  # .....
        else:
            # (Закрытие)
            cls.MENU_POINT_FLAG = False
            cls.MENU_POINT_TEXT = 'Открыть'  # (НЕ РАБОТАЕТ !!!)
            print('***  ЗАКРЫЛИ !  ***')  # .....


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = MainWindow()
    game.start()  # вывод - Окна Игры
```

Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369754/update-label-of-tkinter-menubar-item

Answer (score 0):

Огромное спасибо Сергею Коху! Это действительно решение моего вопроса.
Весь секрет в одной функции - menu.entryconfigure(1, label="Новый текст Пункта-Меню")
Приведу малюсенький демонстративный Пример, сделанный на основе Поста, предоставленного Сергеем Кохом:

```
from tkinter import *

flag = False  # Флаг Работы в Обработчике Пункта-Меню (False/True - Открытие/Закрытие)


def clicked(menu_point):  # Обработчик Пункта-Меню
    global flag

    if flag:
        # (Закрытие)
        flag = False
        menu_point.entryconfigure(0, label="Открыть")  # (Работает !)
        # (.....)
        print('***  ЗАКРЫТИЕ !  ***')  # .....
    else:
        # (Открытие)
        flag = True
        menu_point.entryconfigure(0, label="Закрыть")  # (Работает !)
        # (.....)
        print('***  ОТКРЫТИЕ !  ***')  # .....


# (Главное-Окно)
root = Tk()
root.geometry('+700+200')

# (Меню)
menu_bar = Menu(root)

# (Пункт-Меню - File)
file_menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=False)
file_menu.add_command(label='Открыть', command=lambda: clicked(file_menu))
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label='Выйти')

menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)

root.config(menu=menu_bar)
root.mainloop()
```

Спасибо всем участвующим в обсуждении! Теперь все работает правильно.